# Php mailer using SQL table for emails

Tags: php, mysql

I enjoy learning and doing things on my own, but I have run into a pickle that I don't know how to fix.

I am trying to write a php mass mailer for an announcement system that I can activate within an admin page via a button.

Here is what the current script looks like.

```
function sendStreamAnnounce(){
  global $database, $session, $mailer, $form;      
    $q = "SELECT username,email"
        ."FROM ".TBL_USERS."";
    $result = $database->query($q);
    $num_rows = mysql_numrows($result);

   for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
    $email  = mysql_result($result,$i,"email");

     /* Attempt to send the email with new password */
     if($mailer->sendStreamAnnounce($email))
    $_SESSION['mailed'] = true;
          else{
    $_SESSION['forgotpass'] = false;

     }
      header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
    }
}
```

The current set up leaves me with this

http://puu.sh/1gkgg.jpg

I've somehow adapted this from a "I forgot my password" php script that came with a tutorial-esque backend I am using. I realize some things like "$_SESSION" probably aren't needed.

Any help is welcomed! I know many people don't like spoonfeeding, so hints would help me a ton too.

Thank you guys in advance!

**Edit: I fixed it on my own / with Arun's help!**

```
 function sendStreamNotice(){
  global $database, $session, $mailer, $form;      
    $q = "SELECT username,email "
        ."FROM ".TBL_USERS."";
    $result = $database->query($q);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  if(!$result || ($num_rows < 0)){
  echo "Error displaying info";
  return;
}
  if($num_rows == 0){
  echo "Database table empty";
  return;
}

for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++){
    $email  = mysql_result($result,$i,"email");
    $user = mysql_result($result,$i,"username");

     /* Attempt to send the email with new password */
     if($mailer->sendStreamNotice($user,$email))
    $_SESSION['mailed'] = true;
          else{
    $_SESSION['forgotpass'] = false;

     }
      header("Location: ".$session->referrer);
    }
}
```

The email went through just fine!

http://puu.sh/1gkRx.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);` instead of  `mysql_numrows($result);`

Comment: Oh hey, I fixed it on my own / with Arun's help!

Check the modified original post for the working script!